# How to merge QTableWidget table column headers in PyQT5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside2, qtablewidget

How to merge column headers when creating a PyQt5 table? I need to make a structure in which several columns have one heading or one column has two. You need a table like in the picture:
[image]

Comment: You cannot do that in Designer, it can only be made by code.